# connecting to windows server via remote desktop

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I have a windows server 2008 machine sitting at a host company. The dns server is 64.135.1.20. I set that in the "Preferred DNS server" section when following the below instructions. I set the Default gateway to my gateway ip. I set the Subnet mask to 255.255.255.0. And I set the static ip to 172.27.12.136.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754203(v=ws.10).aspx

When I try to use remote desktop, it asks me for the ip address of the remote machine, but since it is connected through a gateway, how do I exactly connect to that machine?

Comment: If 172.27.12.136 is a public address (accessible from the Internet), then that's what you'd use. If you head to "whatsmyip.org" or alike from that machine, what IP is reported as yours?

Comment: WHen you say a public address, you mean connected to a public switch?

Answer (score 1):

On your WinServer2008 machine, you need to open port 3389 in Windows Firewall to accept incoming RDP.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72675f89-30ea-462b-8bc9-f4f6a81f4760/windows-server-2008-remote-desktop-over-web?forum=winserverTS
Also, you need to make sure that Port Forwarding is configured on your router to 172.27.12.136 : port 3389. This allows incoming RDP requests to pass through to your LAN, which your router will forward directly to the host you have specified.
http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/